# URL rewrite (htaccess) does not work in Wordpress page template with custom script

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following url:

https://example.com/verlicitacion/?slug=example-string

I'm trying to turn her into this one:

https://example.com/tender/example-string

I use wordpress and the path "/verlicitacion/" is a wordpress page, which is actually a php script that I am using as a custom template page and I have saved in the theme directory (wp-content/themes/freelanceengine/verlicitacion.php).

The script captures the variable "_GET['slug']" and obtains information from an external api.

The path "/tender/" does not currently exist on the wordpress site.

In my .htaccess I tried to add this to the top of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^tender/(.+)$ /verlicitacion/?slug=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I try to get in: https://example.com/tender/example-string I get an error 404. (The error page of the theme).

I've been stuck with this for almost two days. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) function,
In your case it should look like this:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^tender/(.+)$','/verlicitacion/?slug=$1','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

**Note:** I don't test this code, It may don't work , You can research about this function and learn more.

**Note 2:** You must flush rules after add/remove a rule, you can use [flush_rewrite_rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) function Or go to `wordpress dashboard > settings > permalink` and save again settings

Comment: Thanks @aidinMC , but doesn't work. I execute the code but nothing happens. I've checked doing `$rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' ); var_dump($rules);`
And I don't see anything added. (I already flushed).